# Deploying shiny app made with golem to shinyapps.io gives Error

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, golem

I am trying to deploy shiny app made with golem to the shinyapps.io . It was working well few days back but now when I am trying to deploy gives following error.
[image]

I tried deploying simple new golem shiny app that also gave the same error.
What is the problem?

Comment: Hey, 

Yes, there is currently an issue with the latest version of `{usethis}` and Shinyapps.io, as tracked here https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/issues/559 

Are you using the dev version of `{usethis}` on your computer ? If yes, can you try with reinstalling the CRAN version ? 

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problems comes with ShinyApps.io and not directly {golem}.
Indeed, {gert} requires a system dependency : `libgit2`, which may not be already installed on ShinyApps.io.
You can open an issue here to ask for this system dependency : https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/issues

There is already an issue about this on {golem} here: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/issues/559

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue by installing old version of the usethis package.